# Gmail signature - text-decoration:none

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, text-decorations

I realise this has been asked many times before so apologies if I'm repeating myself but having followed many other tips on this I'm getting some weird behaviours in Gmail.

If I open the below code in a browser, copy it and then paste it into a Gmail sig (via Settings) the text respects the **text-decoration** attribute (I'm using the span and `!important` as advised by other posts).

I can now create/send emails and the styling is respected.

But if I quit Gmail and then log-in again, the `text-decoration:none` styling is suddenly ignored. The only way to 'repair' is to copy/paste the sig back in again (via Settings).

I'm wondering if something has changed in Gmail as I've been using this sig for a good year or so and it's only recently that I've noticed this behaviour.

Anybody else experienced this (or can see anything wrong with my code)?

```html
<body>
  <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans','Lucida Sans 
        Unicode';font-size:12px;margin:0px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="http://maps.google.com?q=Mainframe North" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none !important;color:rgb(180,180,180);">
          <span style="text-decoration:none !important;color:rgb(180,180,180);">
            82 Silk Street<br>Manchester M4 6BJ
        </span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Updated code as per comments below:

```html
<table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:12px;margin:0px;color:#B4B4B4">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="http://maps.google.com?q=Mainframe North" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
        <span style="text-decoration:none;color:#B4B4B4">
        82 Silk Street<br>Manchester M4 6BJ
        </span>
    </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without `!@important`? Gmail doesn't like it at times.

Comment: Thanks, I have. Same issue. Copy paste the html in via Gmail Settings and everything is fine (i.e. no underline). But if I then close down my Gmail Chrome tab, open a new one and go back to Gmail the underlining comes back.

Comment: Try the colours in hex and change the font to Arial to see if both sticks. Try one at a time. If this doesn't work I will try and recode.

Comment: Also drop the body code, you signature should be tables only.

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid. I've tried your suggestions. I've also tried moving the color into the table style and removing it from the divs. Here's my current code. If it gives any clues the underlining with this code is now blue when I log in/out of gmail.

Comment: So, this makes no sense to me but doing exactly the same steps in Safari (rather than Chrome) seems to have resolved the issue. Same code, different browser. Thanks for your time @Syfer

Answer (score 14):

The issue is a bug with Google's fork of Webkit Layout Engine, Blink.  When just viewing the Gmail Settings page in Chrome, the "text-decoration:none" style tag is completely removed from your signature permanently.

I found a hack to fix this issue though:

1. Either paste your HTML signature into Gmail Settings using any other browser,
2. or do the following:

   - Right-click the underscored element in your signature and inspect
   - In the inspection window, add the "text-decoration:none" back into your style attribute
   - Introduce a text change in the signature like a space so that the "Save Changes" button activates.
   - Save your changes.

Voila, no more underscores ever (or at least until you change your signature once again).

Comment: I see that this answer came after you answered yourself.   This one is more complete, though, and doesn't require you to leave whatever browser you find yourself using.

Comment: This is the only true solution that worked for me

Comment: This is not a real solution, it's a hack. See below tor the real solution, use: text-decoration: unset;

Answer (score 9):

Use `text-decoration: unset;`

This issue still exists in Gmail and since most browsers are now Chromium-based, using "another browser" generally presents the exact same issue.

Adding `text-decoration: none;` via Inspect Element and making a minor change to enable "Save Changes" still works.

Alternatively, use `text-decoration: unset;` instead and paste the signature into Gmail. Gmail doesn't remove `text-decoration: unset;` and the signature loads without links underlined.

Comment: this should be the right answer! thanks mate!

Comment: `text-decoration: unset` works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Using text-decoration: unset instead of text-decoration: none; fixed the issue.
Note: you should use it instead of text-decoration-line: none; too

Comment: This works but you should know that Outlook (native client) does not interpret `text-decoration: unset` correctly and your links will display an underline.

Answer (score 5):

It seems adding and saving my signature in Gmail via Safari (rather than Chrome) fixed my issue.